# App is giving error of Installation failed when running from Android-Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, caching

I am trying to run the app build getting this error

> Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed.
>   Installation failed due to: 'Invalid File:
>   F:\Work_Kartika\Kartika\SiteTrack\timeclock\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'

Whenever I build apk and manually paste it into device, it works but not working from Android Studio
I have already tried invalidate cache and restart, clean project but nothing is working

Comment: Hi! I am running into the same problem. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: My problem was because of Antivirus, antivirus was blocking this process. So i disabled antivirus and it worked for me